# Is rear derailleur hanger numbering standardised?

Tags: terminology, derailleur-hanger, hanger

I broke my hanger, and had to find a replacement.

One listing I found for a "#23" looked quite different, and the seller said:

> These numbers are created by the seller, different sellers may have different number for their own hangers. you just need to check the shape and overall measurement.

**QUESTION**  How common are other numbering schemes, vs defaulting to the [***Wheels Manufacturing*** allocated numbers](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/all-derailleur-hangers/derailleur-hanger-wall-chart.html) ?

| [A Number 23 from Wheels Mfg](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/manufacturers/gt/derailleur-hanger-23.html) | [Auction listing for a **type 23**](https://www.trademe.co.nz/4282447797) | [A Canyon from ~2012](https://www.canyon.com/en-nz/gear/bike-parts/spare-and-wear-parts/spare-wear-parts/derailleur-hanger-no.-23/138072.html) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Comment: To be clear, this is not about the number 23 itself, but the duplication of numbering.

Comment: I was going to say NOT AT ALL, but having just looked up BETD's hanger 23, it  appears to match the shape of the Wheels version, so perhaps they share a scheme. The Pilo D23 is different again. This question is probably best emailed to the three manufacturers mentioned.